# Sending double through I2C from Arduino Pro Mini to ESP8266

Tags: i2c, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm using a Pro Mini as an I2C slave, which computes a double. This double is requested by the ESP8266 WiFi module and it's sent over I2C byte by byte.

Now I'm trying to reassemble the double at the other end but it's not working.
Current code running on ESP8266:

```
// ABOVE SETUP
union {
  byte bytes[4];
  double value;
} bytedouble;

// IN LOOP
while(Wire.available()){
  byte read = Wire.read();
  bytedouble.bytes[num] = read;
  num++;
}
Serial.println(bytedouble.value); // Returns ovf/overflow
```

I found out a `double` on the Arduino Pro Mini is 4 bytes but 8 bytes on the ESP8266. Can I convert this?

Comment: my guess is, you can use `float` on both sides since your Arduino obviously does not provide double precision at all.

Comment: True, but I'm using libraries which return `doubles` in nearly every method. But seeing as `double` and `float` are the same in Arduino, can I just change the `union` to a `float` member? I'll try it! Thanks :)

Comment: I would suggest you converting it explicitly to a `float` in addition to change the `union` to `float`, so that the code does not break in the future in case the definition of `double` changes.

Comment: Thanks it is working perfectly now!!

Answer (score 0):

ESP8266 is 32 bit processor so `sizeof(int)` is 4 and `sizeof(double)` is 8. On ATmega328 `sizeof(int)` is 2 and `sizeof(double)` is 4. However, on both processors `sizeof(float)` is 4 and that is why you could use that workaround you mentioned in the comment.

Since you are dealing with integer numbers it would be better to just use `int` or `uint32_t` instead of `double` in ESP8266's code so the length will be the same as Arduino's `double`. That way you can avoid using floats which generates quite a few bytes of code that is unnecessary.